# When I render, only some emissions and some gloss render, while others doesn't

Tags: rendering

I've worked in blender for a bit over 2 years now, and I've never encountered something like this before. I was modeling a stage (for performances, etc) and when I tried to render, some of the emissions wouldn't render at ALL. Some would, which is very weird. I'd be really grateful if anyone knew what I could do, because I'm completely lost... :/

.blend : [image]

Comment: make sure you enabled render for these lights (ctrl + recursive disables it), and by the way could you put your blend file? this would help make sure

Comment: Hi. For uploading images in future, please use the in-built uploader to place the images in the question body. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand what the problem is. Which picture is the "correct" one? Only thing I can think is to make sure you have all the object enabled to render in the outliner and the object tab.

Comment: reply to ray: okay, will do - reply to icYou: the first one is the rendered one and the second one is the prerendered one. also, how to add a .blend? i dont really know how to, i just made this account to ask this...

Comment: I'm appearently restricted to 30MB and the .blend is 110MB. I honestly have no clue what I should do or how I should add it :/ @icYou520

Comment: I would honestly need to see your file to know. I would correct your original post because you said 1st image is "pre render" but in the comments your say the 2nd image is "pre render". If you can I would erase all the things in your .blend file that you dont need and just leave a few of the things you are having problems with. (To get it under 30MB) then upload it so I can take a look.

Comment: @icYou520 I added the .blend with removed spotlights, but it still has the same problem.

Comment: oh @icYou520 thank you very much! :) very appreciated!!

Comment: Hi. In general it is still useful to have images in a post so if people come across your question in future they can tell if they are having the same problem, whereas with just a blend file it's a lot harder to tell. Also, for people to get notified of comments you will have to '@' them, e.g. '@RayMairlot'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found your problem.

You had certain objects set to NOT render by turning off the camera icon.
Just turn them all back on and it should render fine. 
[image]